# paging in gridview from dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

i have a datset that i save into viewstate and i want to paging on that dataset.

Code for bind gridview

```
DataSet _ds = _fOrderInvoice.ExecuteDataSet();
ViewState["FIOrders"] = _ds.Tables[0];
grdInvoiced.DataSource = _ds;  // bind the gridview
```

Now i want paging on the gridview. So how can i do that from the dataset that i have save into my `ViewState["FIOrders"]`. My gridview is below

```
     <asp:GridView  ID="grdInvoiced" runat="server" Width="100%" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  DefaultSortColumnName="OrderNo"                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridInvoice_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="invoice_sorting" OnRowDataBound="grdInvoice_Rowdatabount" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="OrderNo" ExcelExportFileName="Export_AccountTerms.xls"
 ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdInvoiced_PageIndexChanging">
 <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="View" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="rbtnSelect" GroupName="a" runat="server" />
         <asp:Literal ID="ltOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderNo")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
         </ItemTemplate>
       <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" />
     </asp:TemplateField>    
     </Columns>    
    </asp:GridView>
```

PageIndexChanging event

```
protected void grdInvoiced_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdInvoiced.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex+1;
        if (ViewState["FOrders"] != null)
        {
           DataTable ds = (DataTable)ViewState["FIOrders"];
            grdInvoiced.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex + 1;
            // Collection<FinalizedOrderInvoiceRows> _rows = ViewState["FIOrders"] as Collection<FinalizedOrderInvoiceRows>;
            grdInvoiced.DataSource = ds;
            grdInvoiced.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Your `ViewState` into `DataSet` and `Bind` it to `GridView`

```
protected void grdInvoiced_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdInvoiced.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        if (ViewState["FOrders"] != null)
        {
            DataSet ds =(DataSet) ViewState["FIOrders"] ;
            grdInvoiced.DataSource = ds;
            grdInvoiced.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this is bind with same data again

Comment: @A.Goutam Yes but it will display Records on Next page

Comment: when i click on page 2 gridview bind with same data again

Comment: because i think we are binding with dataset  that hold from our viewstate so this gird show same data again